# Comma usage before coordinating conjunction after a long clause

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, coordinating-conjunctions

It is correct to put a comma before a coordinating conjunction when the second clause is independent of the first, e.g.,

> Sally picked apples, and she placed them in her basket.

but not if you remove the second "she", e.g.,

> Sally picked apples and placed them in her basket.

<del>(Here the second clause, "placed them in her basket" is dependent as it can't be a standalone sentence.)</del>*

What if the first clause is lengthy? E.g.,

> Sally picked apples to sell at the farmers' market, and placed them in her basket.

Here, I feel that avoiding the comma makes the sentence sound wrong, although I can't put my finger on why.

Also, if a comma is warranted in such a situation, how long is long enough?

> Sally picked apples to sell and placed them in her basket.
>
> Sally picked apples to sell at the world-renowned Nettleton Farmers' Market on Tuesday, and placed them in her basket.

---

<sup>*See my answer regarding this error</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This construction is simply a compound predicate — *picked and placed* — with a single subject — *she* — not an independent clause joined to a dependent one — but more on that later.

> We *baked* a cherry pie and *left* it on the counter to cool.

The rule that a comma should not separate the elements of a compound predicate, no matter how many intervening words, [is not controversial](http://copywriter-editor.com/compound-predicate/).

The longer the sentence, however, the greater the temptation to insert a comma. I suspect it's because the sentence is analyzed as two independent clauses where the second has an understood (or elided) subject, much as you are attempting.

> Sally picked apples to sell at the world-renowned Nettleton Farmers' Market on Tuesday, and *she* priced them accordingly.

If the subject is expressed, then the comma is correct; make the subject implicit and the comma should ostensibly disappear.

I have seen countless sentences of this nature — also from careful writers — where a comma is used but the subject is not restated, so I suppose it's just a matter of time before it's considered correct.

Comment: What difference does it make in terms of the comma use whether it is a compound predicate or a dependent clause following an independent one? If I follow, an example of the latter might be, "Sally picked apples to sell at the world-renowned Nettleton Farmers' Market on Tuesday and thought about Isaac Newton." As far as I can tell, there shouldn't be a difference

Comment: Except that "thought about Isaac Newton" isn't a dependent clause.

Comment: Ohhhh. All the talk of separating independent clauses with a comma and coordinating conjunction led me to believe that "put them in her basket", missing the "she" at the start that would make it an independent clause, becomes a dependent clause, when this is a false equivalency

Answer (score 0):

#### A note on my confusion between a dependent clause and a predicate

> Sally picked apples and placed them in her basket.

Here, "placed them in her basket" is *not* a dependent clause, as I originally thought, but a [predicate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar)). A clause contains a subject and a predicate, but "placed them in her basket" does not contain the subject; it is just the predicate. I thought it was a dependent clause because it cannot be a standalone sentence (which it can't), but that doesn't matter because it doesn't fulfil the requirements for being a clause, never mind independent or dependent, in the first place.

---

As the Wikipedia link explains, the traditionalist view of the whole compound predicate would be (in bold)

> Sally **picked apples and placed them in her basket**.

"placed them in her basket" is one part of the compound predicate.

A more recent view is that the predicate is

> Sally **picked** apples and **placed** them **in** her basket.

In this view, predicates are like mathematical functions that take subjects and/or objects as arguments/parameters:

```
picked(Sally, apples)
placed_in(Sally, them/apples, her_basket)
```

The preposition "in" is part of the second predicate. The coordinating conjunction "and" joins the two predicates.